# Facing challenge in SSIS Integration service auto Refresh Between Sql Server 2012 and Oracle 11g )

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, oracle11g, ssis, automation

I have created an integration service, well with the help of colleague. We are getting data from an Oracle table and bulk insert to SQL server using SSIS. It's working fine when we execute run/debug in Visual Studio. Now, one issue we have is how we can automate the process so that one of us does not have to do it manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SQL Server job directly, my preference is to create a maintenance plan.

1. Open SSMS and goto Management => Maintenance plans
2. Right click and select "New Maintenance Plan"
3. Name it and click 'OK'
4. Drag "Execute T-SQL Statement Task" from tool box to design area
5. Configure
6. I highly recommend adding a Notify Operator Task for when it fails.
7. Click on Calendar Icon at top to schedule
8. Save and step back, your task is now scheduled

Comment: Hello @Brian, Managed to move from step 1 to 4. But cannot find how to configure and query from oracle DB in my SSMS or Execute my integration services created earlier! Thanks